# When does Postgres check unique constraints?

Tags: postgresql, unique-constraint

I have a column `sort_order` with a unique constraint on it.
The following SQL fails on Postgres 9.5:

```
UPDATE test
SET sort_order = sort_order + 1;

-- [23505] ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "test_sort_order_key"
--   Detail: Key (sort_order)=(2) already exists.
```

Clearly, if the `sort_order` values were unique before the update, they will still be unique after the update. Why is this?

**The same statement works fine on Oracle and MS SQL, but also fails on MySQL and SQLite.**

---

Here's the complete setup code for a SQL fiddle:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;
CREATE TABLE test (
  val        TEXT,
  sort_order INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

INSERT INTO test
VALUES ('A', 1), ('B', 2);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Postgres decides to check constraints of type `IMMEDIATELY` at a different time than proposed in the SQL standard.

Specifically, the documentation for [`SET CONSTRAINTS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-set-constraints.html) states (emphasis mine):

> NOT NULL and CHECK constraints are always checked immediately when a row is inserted or modified **(not at the end of the statement)**. Uniqueness and exclusion constraints that have not been declared DEFERRABLE are also checked immediately.

Postgres chooses to execute this query using a plan that results in a temporary collision for `sort_order` and **IMMEDIATELY** fails. Note that means that **for the same schema and the same data, the same query may work or fail depending on the execution plan.**

You'll have to make the constraint `DEFERRABLE` or `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED`, which delays verification of the constraint until the end of the transaction or up to the point where a statement `SET CONSTRAINTS ... IMMEDIATE` is executed.

Addendum from @HansGinzel's comment:

> for `COPY`, it seems, that (even IMMEDIATE) constraints are tested after all data are COPYied.

Comment: Postgres doesn't have a "different idea about what `IMMEDIATELY` means". It is a documented difference from the standard, in implementation of checking UNIQUE constraints.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: Thanks, I corrected the wording. Do you happen to know where in the SQL standard this is specified to make the answer even more complete? Unfortunately, I don't have a copy of it. Feel free to edit my answer :-)

Comment: For COPY, it seems, that (even IMMEDIATE) constraints are tested after all data are COPYied.

Comment: @HansGinzel Thanks, that's an interesting fact! I'll include it in the answer to make it a bit more visible.